# Spring Boot CRUD REST API + Spring Data JPA + H2 DB: Getting NPE on tests but not on Postman

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jpa, nullpointerexception, crud

I'm working on some exercises to familiarize myself with spring framework and working with REST API's. I did pass the exercise, but not with my original implementation. I'd like to know why I was getting NPE on tests but not on Postman.

The test threw NPE when trying to solve this quiz:

```
{
  "title": "Math4",
  "text": "Which of the following is equal to 4?",
  "options": ["2*3", "5*8", "8*0", "1*5"],
  "answer": null
}
```

When I use Postman to post this quiz to the dB and solve, everything works fine.

[image: Post Quiz]
[image: Solve Quiz]

But when I run it through the test I receive the following:

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at engine.presentation.controllers.QuizController.solveQuiz(QuizController.java:44) ~[main/:na]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:170) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.1.0-m3"
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["src/resources"]

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
}
```

application.settings

```
server.port=8889
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true

# H2 data source setup
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:../quizdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect


# Automatically update tables when persistence objects have changed
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# Setup for the H2 console, used for viewing data in the database
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false

# Show SQL statements generated by Spring ORM
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Quiz.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "quizzes")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "id",
        "title",
        "text",
        "options"
})
public class Quiz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private int id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Title is required")
    private String title;

    @NotBlank(message = "Text is required")
    private String text;

    @NotEmpty(message = "There must be at least 2 options")
    @Size(min = 2, message = "There must be at least 2 options")
    private LinkedHashSet<String> options;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private HashSet<Integer> answer;

    public void setAnswer(HashSet<Integer> answer) {
        this.answer = Optional.ofNullable(answer).orElseGet(HashSet::new);
    }
}
```

QuizController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class QuizController {

    private final QuizService quizService;

    @Autowired
    public QuizController(QuizService quizService) {
        this.quizService = quizService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/quizzes")
    public Iterable<Quiz> getQuizzes() {
        return quizService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/quizzes/{id}")
    public Quiz getQuiz(@PathVariable @Min(0) int id) {
        return quizService.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/quizzes")
    public Quiz saveQuiz(@RequestBody @Valid Quiz quiz) {
        return quizService.save(quiz);
    }

    @PostMapping("/quizzes/{id}/solve")
    public Response solveQuiz(@RequestBody @Valid AnswerDto answer,
                          @PathVariable @Min(0) int id) {
        return Response.builder()
                .success(quizService.findById(id).getAnswer().equals(answer.getAnswer()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

QuizService.java:

```
    @Service
public class QuizService {
    private final QuizRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public QuizService(QuizRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Iterable<Quiz> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Quiz findById(int id) {
        Optional<Quiz> quiz = repository.findById(id);

        if (quiz.isEmpty()) {
            throw new QuizNotFoundException(id);
        }

        return quiz.get();
    }

    public Quiz save(Quiz quiz) {
        return repository.save(quiz);
    }
}
```

What I do not understand is how a Quiz is being created with a null answer field if the setAnswer method doesn't ever set the field to null. From what I understand, and please correct me if I am mistaken. When JSON is deserialized to object with @RequestBody, it uses the default (no argument) constructor and the defined setter methods to instantiate the object. Also, why am I unable to replicate the issue on Postman?

This is just for educational purposes. Even though I solved the problem, I want to understand where I went wrong to begin with. Any help is truly appreciated.

EDIT: For clarification, if a null value gets passed as the answer when creating a Quiz object an empty HashSet is created. This should deserialize to an empty array, as shown in the postman images above. When I post the answer to the quiz, I receive the success response because the answer is [];

Comment: Please also post the test. Seems like the `QuizService` is not autowired into the `QuizController`.

Comment: the test are being generated from a 3rd party, I do not have access to the test being run besides printing some statements to the console as methods are called. I did edit my post and add the QuizService class. I have the repository Autowired through the constructor, and the service Autowired through the constructor on the QuizController class as well. Is that wrong?

Comment: Constructor injection is perfectly fine. I'd say, it's even the more progressive approach compared to field injection. From the stack trace it's not clear which variable is `null`. If it runs locally but not in the test, my first guess would be `quizService`. But it may also be the return value of the first `quizService.findById(id).getAnswer()`. Without seeing the test setup, it's hard to say.

Comment: @hpoettker the method returns quiz or throws exception

`public Quiz findById(int id) {
        Optional<Quiz> quiz = repository.findById(id);

        if (quiz.isEmpty()) {
            throw new QuizNotFoundException(id);
        }

        return quiz.get();
    }`

Comment: @hpoeeker I print to console on solveQuiz the Quiz object.

`Quiz(id=6, title=Math4, text=Which of the following is equal to 4?, options=[2*3, 5*8, 8*0, 1*5], answer=null)
2021-08-08 10:26:48.784 ERROR 4840 --- [io-8889-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
quizService.findById(id).getAnswer().equals(answer.getAnswer())
```

fails when the first `getAnswer()` returns `null`, on which `equals` cannot be invoked.

You can use null-safe `Objects::equals` instead:

```
Objects.equals(quizService.findById(id).getAnswer(), answer.getAnswer())
```

The problem is that the test sends the quiz jsons without an explicit `answer` field. In that case your setter is not invoked by Jackson. To enforce the logic that is currently in the setter, a constructor with `@JsonCreator` should help.

Comment: Yes I understand that to be the issue as well, the question is why getAnswer returns null if my setter method never sets answer to null.

Comment: `public void setAnswer(HashSet<Integer> answer) {
        this.answer = Optional.ofNullable(answer).orElseGet(HashSet::new);
    }`

Comment: this is the differenct from the test and postman:

Comment: `Quiz(id=6, title=Math4, text=Which of the following is equal to 4?, options=[2*3, 5*8, 8*0, 1*5], answer=null)
AnswerDto(answer=[])`

Comment: Quiz(id=48, title=Math4, text=Which of the following is equal to 4?, options=[2*3, 5*8, 8*0, 1*5], answer=[])
AnswerDto(answer=[])

Comment: In both cases answer was set to null. In test the null value persisted to the field, in Postman the null value was properly converted to HashSet, so no error.

Comment: The I guess, the test creates the persisted quizzes in a different way. Maybe `@JsonCreator` can help you enforce that `answer` is never `null`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895462/how-do-i-force-jackson-to-use-an-objects-setters

Comment: Yes this is how I ended up passing the test was defining a constructor with JsonCreator and setting JsonProperty on the method parameters. I was just looking for an explanation on why I had to do this to pass the test.

Comment: Because the test sends the json without an `answer` field. With postman you set it explicitly to `null`. That makes a difference with the setter.

Comment: I didn't consider that as in previous test this wasn't the case. This seems to cause the same error. Thank you. Please post as answer.

Comment: Or the simplest solution of all, add a default value to the field. so when the class is created it already has the empty hashSet. It just came to me and hit me in the face list a ton of bricks.